# How Can I Download discord.py on MacOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, syntax-error, discord.py

Whenever I try and download discord.py by doing:

- `python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py[voice]"` it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
- `python3 -m install -U discord.py` it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
- `pip install discord.py` it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
- `python3 -m pip install discordpy` it says `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

What should I do? I've tried all of them separately and I've tried downloading Python 3.6 and Python 3.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should re read the tutorial you followed. The command should be **either**

- `python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py[voice]"`
- `python3 -m install -U discord.py`
- `pip install discord.py`

Also, I think you could try `python3 -m pip install discordpy`

Comment: I have done all of these separately and none worked. I re-read the tutorial and everything is the exact same thing.

Comment: Could you then update your question with all the separate commands you tried (or at least the one correct command you tried), and the output you got from that? Feel free to copy paste as much of your terminal as needed to get help faster

Comment: This answer is correct, the output should never be `syntaxerror...` if you're typing the exact commands, provide screenshots of the entered commands, and provide the entire error output if you haven't already